# Dual graph of a tree

Tags: trees, planar-graphs

It is stated [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/euler/interdig.html) that:

> For any connected embedded planar graph G define the dual graph G* by
>   drawing a vertex in the middle of each face of G, and connecting the
>   vertices from two adjacent faces by a curve e* through their shared
>   edge e. Note that G**=G.

Given any planar drawing of a tree $G$ is its dual graph simply $K_1$? But then how does one justify $G^{**}=G$?

Comment: Maybe it only works, when $G$ has more than one face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual graph need not be simple. Here’s a badly drawn example of a black tree with $6$ vertices (and therefore $5$ edges and $1$ face) and its red dual: the dual has $1$ vertex, $5$ edges, all of which are loops, and $6$ faces.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. What is the correct definition of a dual graph? How are its edges defined?

Comment: @Shahab: The definition that you gave is basically right; it just fails to take into account that an edge of $G$ may border only one face, in which case it gives rise to a loop in $G^*$ at the vertex corresponding to that face.